# No such file or directory error using getctime()

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to find the last created folder name, using python:

```
directory = mx.get_env('WORKDIR')+'/Benchmarks/SPECjvm2008/SPECjvm2008/r‌​esults/'
folders = os.walk(directory).next()[1]
creation_times = [(folder, os.path.getctime(folder)) for folder in folders]
creation_times.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort by creation time
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
  File "/home/taleporos/.jenkins/workspace/MaxineBench/graal/mxtool/mx.py", line 3588, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/taleporos/.jenkins/workspace/MaxineBench/graal/mxtool/mx.py", line 3577, in main
    retcode = c(command_args)
  File "/home/taleporos/.jenkins/workspace/MaxineBench/maxine/mxmaxine/commands.py", line 432, in specjvmregression
    dirfinder('specjvm')
  File "/home/taleporos/.jenkins/workspace/MaxineBench/maxine/mxmaxine/commands.py", line 394, in dirfinder
    print 'Folder: ', [(folder, os.path.getctime(folder)) for folder in folders]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 72, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SPECjvm2008.002'
```

Comment: Use the absolute path.

Comment: `os.path.getctime(folder)` -> `os.path.getctime(directory + folder)`

Comment: The error message doesn't include any of the lines of code you show.

Comment: the error was irrelevant to the other files, that's why i didn't add them. It just needed the absolute path. Thanks m8s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the whole path:

```
creation_times = [(folder, os.path.getctime(directory+folder)) for folder in folders]
creation_times.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort by creation time
```